# How to select multiple radiobuttons on one page?

Tags: html, radio-button

I want to build a questionnaire in HTML. Every question in the list can be answered by selecting one of four radiobuttons.

The problem I am facing is that I can only select one choice *on the whole page*, while I want to be able to select one choice *per question*.

When I have a list of questions and I have picked an alternative for question 1, I turn to question 2.

When I select an alternative for question 2, the chosen radiobutton for question 1 is deselected.

The radiobuttons for different questions have different names, the radiobuttons for 1 question have the same name. I included every question in a fieldset, but that does not work.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Share some example code, please.

Comment: Please note that this site is not a code writing service. If you
[edit] your question to describe what you have tried so far and where
you are stuck, then we can try to help with specific problems. You
should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You have to group your radio buttons by `name`:

```
 <input type="radio" name="group1" value="one">One<br>
 <input type="radio" name="group1" value="two">Two<br>
 <input type="radio" name="group1" value="three">Three<br>
 <input type="radio" name="group1" value="four">Four<br><br>

 <input type="radio" name="group2" value="a">a<br>
 <input type="radio" name="group2" value="b">b<br>
 <input type="radio" name="group2" value="c">c<br>
 <input type="radio" name="group2" value="d">d<br>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ajjbfj0v/2/

Comment: Note that the OP states: "The radiobuttons for different questions have different names, the radiobuttons for 1 question have the same name".

Comment: Thanks Oscar, but as Jiri Tousek mentioned, I already had the names for different questions were already different, so this does not help the problem.